# Is it possible to specify the lifetime on match variables in rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

For example:

```
enum FooBar {
  Bar(Vec<int>),
  Other
}

fn main() {
  let default:&[int] = [];
  let x = Bar(Vec::from_slice([1, 2, 3]));
  let y = match(x) {
    Bar(z) => z.slice(0, z.len()),
    _ => default
  };
  println!("{}", y);
}
```

In this example the slice is not valid because of the lifetime on z; but we *know* that the actual data here (x) is valid for the entire block.

Is there some 'a syntax you can use here to help hint this to compiler? If so, how do you do it?

(I believe I've seen some kind of 'a match { } or match x 'a { } / something syntax in the past, but I can't find any examples now that I'm looking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, there is some syntax, though it is not as explicit on lifetimes as you mean and in fact it is more general. By doing `match` as you do you are actually moving `x` into the match, so it is consumed. No wonder that `z.slice(...)` can't escape the block. But you can avoid moving `x` into the match by using reference patterns (note the `ref` before `z`):

```
let default: &[int] = [];
let x = Bar(vec![1, 2, 3]);
let y = match x {
    Bar(ref z) => z.slice(0, z.len()),
    Other => default
};
println!("{}", y);
```

This way `x` is not moved into match block - its internals are borrowed instead. This program compiles and prints out `[1, 2, 3]`.